# SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and Basic Search is not working

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I am using a server farm installation for sharepoint 2010. I used the following website to implement sharepoint search http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/. But I am getting errors. When I do people search I get "Internal server error exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted" but when I do all sites search I get "Internal server error exception: , Correlation ID: 9c22743c-b9d0-4ef3-a547-785666c10d46

"

Comment: What do the ULS logs say?

Comment: its a pretty big list. I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: How about the Event Viewer list? Look under windows>>Application logs when you open it

Comment: Insufficient SQL database permissions for user 'Name: GEFSERVER\Administrator SID: S-1-5-21-2965956676-2170545589-382481574-500 ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation' in database 'SharePoint2010_Config' on SQL Server instance 'GEFSERVER'. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_GetProductVersions', database 'SharePoint2010_Config', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Well there is a start. The user you are using to run the search service application doesnt seem to have permissions to the database. Modify user permissions on the respected db or use an account that already has sufficient permissions.